# Can you list multiple features within the same Schema.org "LocationFeatureSpecification"?

Tags: schema.org

I am working on Schema.org `Resort` schema for a ton of resorts on a travel website and am trying to find the most efficient ways of filling out the schema with regards to amenities.

The current code looks something like this:

```json
"amenityFeature": [
  {
    "@type":"http://schema.org/LocationFeatureSpecification",
    "name":"Spa",
    "value":"true"
  },
  {
    "@type":"http://schema.org/LocationFeatureSpecification",
    "name":"Internet Access",
    "value":"true"
  },
  {
    "@type":"http://schema.org/LocationFeatureSpecification",
    "name":"Tennis Courts",
    "value":"true"
  }
]
```

My question is, can I write it like this instead to shorten lines of code:

```json
{
  "@type":"http://schema.org/LocationFeatureSpecification",
  "name":[
    "Spa", "Internet Access", "Tennis Courts"
  ],
  "value":"true"
}
```

When I test it in Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool, it doesn’t give any errors. Here is what it looks like in the SDTT when I write it the short way:

[image]

And here is what it looks like if I do it the first/long way:

[image]

If I do it the short way, I want to make sure all those items are getting listed as amenities and not just different names for the same amenity. Otherwise, I'll go the long route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, each [`LocationFeatureSpecification`](https://schema.org/LocationFeatureSpecification) represents *one* feature:

> Specifies a location feature by providing a structured value representing **a feature** of an accommodation as a property-value pair of varying degrees of formality.

Your second snippet would represent one feature with multiple names.